# How can I distribute a Python application into an empty environment?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, python-venv, python-packaging

I have a python3 app that I have written I need to install on a production, linux, server.  For various reasons, this linux installation is very barebones.  It will not have any version of python.  It will not have Docker or anything similar.  I don't know why that is the case, but those are my requirements.  How can I deploy my python app to this server so it will function.

I had a few ideas:

- Create an binary with something like pyinstaller.  I have heard, however, that this does not really work very well and can be flaky.
- Package up python in my install package with instructions to install it.  This is not great, as it is supposed to be a zero-install package (although this might be acceptable).
- Could this be as simple as just creating a python virtual environment?  It seems like that includes the python interpreter (venv/bin/python).  Someone I work with told me that will not work and python still needs to be installed on host environment.  Not sure why.

I am going to play with this last option and see if it works.

Comment: I don't know all the deep details, but a virtual environment creates a set of files that really just call the 'real'/base python install. so if you just copy the venv folder to the new machine and try to run it, it'll try to call into the base python interpreter that doesn't exist there.

Comment: There are several programs like PyInstaller (you already mentioned), py2exe ,py2app to convert your program into stand alone executable. These bundle all the dependencies into a single executable and you can run without installing python.

Comment: There are a bunch of solutions already mentioned. One that I have not seen mentioned yet is pyoxidizer: https://pyoxidizer.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pyoxidizer_overview.html -- It will put your application, its dependencies, and the Python interpreter itself in a single-file executable format that should be easy to redistribute and deploy (install). -- Anyway it is debatable whether or not this question is on topic for StackOverflow, because it is quite vague (or hides multiple questions), also you could quite easily find answers online.

Comment: PyOxidizer is awesome, but I feel like it targets a different use case tbh... Python itself was created to be embedded inside an actual program, at least at first. @sinoroc

Comment: @TimothyH, under the hood, that is what pyoxidizer does, it embeds the Python interpreter in some (Rust) application, but that is technical implementation detail that no one really needs to know (not the packager, not the end user).

Comment: Yeah, but I've used it primarily for interop between the two, the only point here is that you'd be adding not only an entirely separate toolchain to the dev stack just to use it as a wrapper, but you're also depending on it itself (granted this part alone is more the same as relying on Pyinstaller or something). One good use case I had was launching via rust to show a splash screen because of how long python took to init PySimpleGui/PyInstaller on some machines, wrapped that in PyOxidizer and also handled some library logic from Rust, worked great. Point remains, ultimately it is bloat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could compile the .py file to an .exe file with the nuitka compiler use `pip install nuitka` and then you can compile the .py with `nuitka --onefile --disable-console main.py` you can try to leave out the --disable-console if you need the console. The Nuitka compiler doesnt compile like Pyinstaller by just packing the python interpreter. Nuitka compiles using gcc meaning c code. The .exe is then not obfuscated but actually compiled.

Here is a proper youtube tutorial for Nuitka: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z2aHkuBCLN8

Comment: I am not saying I will stay with this option... creating binaries from python scripts just doesn't seem like a great way to go.  Having said that, this worked straight out of the box.. no errors.  (pyinstaller getting dependency errors I can't seem to resolve).   You deserve a green check just for that.  Thank you

Comment: @Wanderer Im happy it worked for you but even though python is not intended to be compiled this method uses c and can reach the performance of c because it is.

Answer (score -1):

Honestly at the end of the day, Python was created for use as an embedded language, if you can't have anything installed that should work, you would need to [read the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html) for embedding. Otherwise there are various answers. The aforementioned embedding should "just work" at every use case. NOTE: You will need to ensure that all packages are available.